# Android camera save past 30 seconds of video

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

Any Idea of how i could write an app for android that save the past 30 seconds of camera video? Would like to make an app to record something like sport highlights and such.

Read about grafika and there seems to be a function that does what i want, but it seems that its code has not been updated in some time. (grafica https://github.com/google/grafika)
Would like some suggestions on an up to date approach on the subject.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.